# OpenCL compiler white-space problems

Tags: opencl, cloo

I'm trying to get started with OpenCL but came across weird behavior of the OpenCL compiler with respect to white-space and can't seem to find any documentation about that.

C-style single-line comments (`// foo`) immediately cause a meaningless build error: `At end of source: error: expected a "}"`. Multi-line comments (`/* bar */`) seem to work fine.

Line breaks seem to get stripped without adding whitespace which can cause errors. This example will not compile because of that:

```
__kernel
void TestKernel() {}

line 1: error: identifier "__kernelvoid" is undefined
```

This may totally depend on my machine and/or configuration but can somebody confirm that these things should not be this way?

I am using OpenCL via Cloo from .net/C#. The driver is from AMD `OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (1642.5)`

Comment: \n cures sometimes "especially with #define"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I was doing this:

```
var program = new ComputeProgram(context, File.ReadAllLines(filename));
```

`File.ReadAllLines()` returns an array of strings without the line-break characters which is the root of the errors I was getting.

Using `File.ReadAllTest()` instead fixed all the problems:

```
var program = new ComputeProgram(context, File.ReadAllText(filename));
```

But in my opinion some of the blame goes to either Cloo or the OpenCL API for accepting a string array but just concatenating it together..

Comment: JavaCL behaves in a similiar way. If the last line does not end with a line feed, the compilation aborts.